# Снятие данных о частоте, превышающей период дискретизации

Tags: математика, анализ-данных, физика, компьютерное-зрение

Необходимо измерить частоту колебаний объекта с помощью видео, записанного на камеру (для упрощения, пусть это будто колеблющаяся точка).
В таком случае фреймрейт камеры должен быть как минимум в два раза больше частоты колебаний, иначе будет потеряна информация о положениях этой точки -> не удастся установить частоту.

Вопрос: как можно обойти это ограничение?

Мне приходит в голову только накопление данных с последующим "угадыванием" периода колебаний, после чего можно будет разрезать данные по периодам, наложить их друг на друга и узнать частоту.

Comment: Учитывая, что у камеры есть выдержка и связанная с ней смазанность движущихся объектов - думаю, достаточно всего одного снимка, чтобы по этой самой смазанности определить скорость объекта и как следствие частоту (но это не точно, на практике не проверял)

Comment: да, эффект роллинг шаттер использовали какие-то ребята для распознования голоса через видео. но в данном случае это не подходит, потому что будет страдать точность, а также на используемой камере с глобал шаттер затвор (у него нет этого эффекта смазанности).

Comment: Формально теорему Котельникова никто не отменял, так что вроде бы опять же формально однозначное решение не получится. Но есть такое подозрение, что если, грубо говоря, снимать несколькими камерами с разными частотами, то что-то можно будет вытащить...

Comment: Решение возможно только в некоторых частных случаях, например, если частота объекта наблюдения стабильна, а частотой камеры мы можем управлять, или мы заранее знаем частоты объекта с погрешностью, меньше частоты камеры. Или есть дополнительное оборудование, например, стробосткоп.